# JavaScript Appending Rather Than Overwriting Using InnerHTML Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, sharepoint-online

So this is a weird one as every topic I've found on the subject has the exact opposite of my problem.

I'm using some JavaScript in SharePoint Online to replace the innerHTML of some  elements, but whenever the function runs it is appending content rather than overwriting it.

I've tried the JS method of setting the innerHTML to something else first, then to the value (no luck), and also moving it to a jQuery call to set it. In both cases it does the same thing. Same problem observed on both Edge and Chrome.

Code is below - any ideas? (Have not included the whole script, just the specific function as it's quite a big script and the other bits are working as expected).

```
function getThisCompany() {
  thisCompanyEnum = thisCompany.getEnumerator();
  while (thisCompanyEnum.moveNext()) {
      var currentCompany = thisCompanyEnum.get_current();
      var thisCompanyId = currentCompany.get_item('ID');
      var thisCompanyName = currentCompany.get_item('companyName');
      var thisCompanyPhone = currentCompany.get_item('companyPhone');
      var thisCompanyUrl = currentCompany.get_item('companyUrl');
      var thisCompanyLogo = currentCompany.get_item('companyLogo');

      // Check for a null value - if it is null console throws an error and stops the script, so load a default logo
      if (thisCompanyLogo == null) {
        thisCompanyLogo = "https://consiliumuk.sharepoint.com/POC/minicrm/CRM%20Images/nologo.png";
      }
      else {
        thisCompanyLogo = thisCompanyLogo.get_url();
      }

      var thisCompanyAddress = currentCompany.get_item('companyAddress');
      var thisCompanyMarkupBlock = "<table><tr><td colspan=2><b>";
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += thisCompanyName;
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += "</b></td></tr><tr><td colspan=1 valign=top><img height=100 width=100 src='";
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += thisCompanyLogo;
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += "' /></td><td colspan=1 valign=top>";
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += thisCompanyAddress;
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += "<p /><i>";
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += thisCompanyPhone;
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += "</i><br /><a href=";
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += thisCompanyUrl;
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += ">Visit company website</a></td></tr></table><p /><input id='loadExtended' type='button' value='Load' onClick='loadExtendedDetails(";
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += thisCompanyId;
      thisCompanyMarkupBlock += ");' />";
      alert(thisCompanyMarkupBlock);

      //document.getElementById('detailsSpace').innerHTML = "Loading...";
      //document.getElementById('detailsSpace').innerHTML = thisCompanyMarkupBlock;
      jQuery("#detailsSpace").html(thisCompanyMarkupBlock);
    }   
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .html(), you can use clear and append, yo ensure your container is empty, something like:

```
jQuery("#detailsSpace").empty(); // Before while

while ([...]){
   [...]
   jQuery("#detailSpace").append(thisCompanyMarkupBlock); // Instead of html()
}
```

Comment: with this mindset you'll end up duct taping everything in your code.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Would you tell me the reason? As a solution it works, but i always want to learn more, so if it's not good at all i want to know the reasoning

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal i do agree a decent templating engine would be better than all that plain JS concatenation. *however*, it'd be nicer if you posted something helpful rather than just a sneer at a viable answer. furthermore, i feel that remark would be more in place for OP's code than this answer.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I agree too that using a template would be far way better than plain JS, but he asked for a solution for this specific problem. If he asked for other ways to do it i'd have wrote more workarounds. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: @Diego I never said a word about templating engine ;) I wrote my comment because OP's question challenges the usual behaviour of `innerHTML` property - `Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element`. So instead of solving that, your answer provides a mere workaround. I agree your answer might solve the problem but this is duct taping approach for me, since the original unintended behaviour isn't yet solved and still present in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - there was another function where because of a loop it was keeping the previous set of returned HTML when it got reprocessed. The jquery.empty() function was put in at the right place along with declaring the string null again, fixed now.